# Not getting output of LEX program

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I am trying to run a lex program to find number of vowels and consonants in a given string. The program accepts the input but not giving the output. After giving the input , the program accepts the input but not giving the output and also it is not terminating.
Please help me in finding out the mistake.
I am also attaching code here

```
%{ 
#include<stdio.h>
int vowel=0;
int consonant=0; 
%} 
%% 
[aeiouAEIOU] {vowel++ ;} 
[a-zA-Z] {consonant++ ; } 
%% 
int yywrap()
{
return 1;
} 
int main() 
{ 
printf("Enter the string :"); 
yylex();
printf("Number of vowels are:  %d\n",vowel); 
printf("Number of consonants are:  %d\n",consonant); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Which input are you entering and how? Note that, without any return statements, `yylex` will read until the end of the stream, not the end of the line. So if you're entering a line with the keyboard and pressing enter, that's not enough to make `yylex` return.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I have got the output with a little bit of addition in code.
The updated code is as follows:

```
%{ 
#include<stdio.h>
int vowel=0;
int consonant=0; 
%} 
%% 
[aeiouAEIOU] {vowel++ ;} 
[a-zA-Z] {consonant++ ; } 
"\n" return 0;
%% 
int yywrap()
{
return 1;
} 
int main() 
{ 
printf("Enter the string :"); 
yylex();
printf("Number of vowels are:  %d\n",vowel); 
printf("Number of consonants are:  %d\n",consonant); 
return 0; 
}
```